# Zend Framework 1.12 search query in 2 tables

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, union

I'm trying to get all products connected with search result.

I've got 2 tables: `$products` and `$tags`.

```
$products = new Application_Model_DbTable_Products();
$tags = new Application_Model_DbTable_Tags();
```

After receiving a search query which is a string, in my controller part I try to get all products connected with this query.

```
$select1 = $products->select()->where("product_name LIKE '%$query%' OR product_desc LIKE '%$query%'");
$select2 = $tags->select()->where("name LIKE '%$query%'");
$this->view->products = $products->fetchAll($select1)
```

The problem is to combine this 2 selects (`$select1, $select2`) to get 1 array of objects (`$this->view->products`).

Comment: Are tags somehow related to the products? If yes you can do a join on the two tables. If not I think you are trying to get and array containing two different types of objects (Products and Tags) ?